# django forms and request in same http page

Tags: django, request, render, django-crispy-forms

OK so I'm trying to create a page that will have a search form of Well,
I get the contents of the search in the page ex: (http://127.0.0.1:8000/wellsheet/ODN20)
I used this code

urls.py file

```
path('wellsheet/<slug:Evt_id>', views.wellsets, name='WellSheetg'),
```

views.py

```
def wellsets(request, Evt_id):
    serchedWl = WellSheets.objects.filter(WellID__WellID__exact=Evt_id)
    context ={
        'title': 'Eventstopost',
        'Wellslist':serchedWl,
        'WIDSHT':Evt_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'Home/WELLINFO/W_TchD/wellshts.html', context)
```

in addition to this page I want to add another well ,and I have a model form to add in same page using crispy.

urls.py

```
path('wellsheet/<slug:WeelN>/', views.welshetad2.as_view(), name='AddWellSheet'),
```

views.py

```
class welshetad2(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = WellSheets
template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/W_TchD/wellshts.html'
form_class = UploadWSF2
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

but in my page I can't render the crispy form

```
<div class="border p-3 mb-3 mt-3 w3-round-large w3-light-grey border-dark">
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row"><div class="form-group mb-0">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            </div></div>
```

this is my page 
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxUBo.jpg)

My goal is to see a page like this

[My Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOod9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is solved by using one def as:

views.py

```
def wellsets(request, pk):
serchedWl = WellSheets.objects.filter(WellID__WellID__exact=pk)
form= UploadWSF2(request.POST or None)
context ={
    'title': 'Wellssht',
    'Wellslist':serchedWl,
    'WIDSHT':pk,
    'form':form,
}  
return render(request, 'Home/WELLINFO/W_TchD/wellshts.html', context)
```

and the page will show tow results a Form and results of search